# On an iPhone, how to play a specific sound when I receive an email from a given person

Tags: iphone, ios, automation, shortcuts-app

This is in the context of the Shorcuts app, automation.

The sound file could be anything in the iPhone, starting, say from a mp3 file on a computer.

I can't find an obvious way to just specify a file to be played when I receive an email from a given person.